# Azure Cosmos Graph DB Compound Conditional Query

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

Using Azure's Cosmos DB Graph Database I have a sample DB:[Sample Graph Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2Nrp.png).  I am trying to expand a simple query into one that returns all the "Person" Nodes that have a "Skill Ratings" Node where MS_OFFICE=FAIL AND .NET=TRUE.

Current Query Thus Far:

```
ENGLISH DESCRIPTION: Find "Person Nodes" whose "Skill Ratings" Node match MS_OFFICE=FAIL

GREMLIN QUERY: g.V().hasLabel("Person").as("PersonNode")
  .out("scored").as("SkillNode")
  .has("skill_Name","MS_OFFICE")
  .has("skill_Value","FAIL")
  .select("PersonNode").by("Name")
```

To modify the existing query to include a conditional element, I was wondering if I am just missing a specific traversal step in the TinkerPop Documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need something like this:

```
g.V().hasLabel("Person").
  where(out("scored").
         has("skill_name","MS_OFFICE").
         has('skill_value","FAIL")).
  values('name')
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick suggestion.  However upon testing in Azure I get the following Error: GraphCompileException ExceptionMessage :
 Gremlin Query Compilation Error: Unable to find any method 'filter' .  

I'm assuming that the inability to find the filter step is due to Azure Cosmos Graph DB having not implemented the Filter Step as defined by https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/gremlin-support ?

Comment: sorry i forgot they dont' have `filter` yet - does CosmosDB allow an anonymous traversal to be passed to `where()` step? in other words what happens if you change `filter()` to `where()`?

Comment: Replacing filter() with a where() does indeed make the code execute.  Currently testing the query to ensure that I can get it to work a AND/OR's:
`g.V().hasLabel('Person').as('personNode')
 .where(out('scored')
 .has('skillName','MS_OFFICE')
 .has('skillValue','FAIL'))
 .and(out('scored')
 .has('skillName','Eating')
 .has('skillValue','PASS'))
.select('personNode').by('name')`

Comment: the `as()` and `select().by()` are not necessary from what i can tell.

Comment: right; the as() is just a means to help me follow where along the graph I am and the select().by() formats the data such that Java can use the results.

Comment: you don't need the `as()`. why not just do `values('name')` as i have above? you don't want to label steps with `as()` unless there is a reason to.